# Stop Segue and pass to next view the content of textfield shown in alert - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I need to stop a segue transition and show alert with a `textField`. 
But then, when I press "OK" button, I want to pass to the next view, the content of the `textfield`.

The problem is when I declare a view controller destination in `prepareForSegue` and I pass the text, because this is nil. I write my example:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var shouldSegue:Bool = true
    if identifier == "FirstToSecondView" {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "End the First", message: "Are you sure you want to end the first?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{ (textField) in
               textField.placeHolder = "Name"
        }
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            println("OK Pressed")
            let tf = alert.textFields?.First as? UITextField

            //name is a declared variable above
            if tf != nil {self.name = tf.text}

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("WorkoutToSummary", sender: self)
        }
        var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            println("Cancel Pressed")
            shouldSegue = false
        }
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    }
    return shouldSegue
}
```

And then in the `prepareForSegue`, I put that:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    var namePass: String = self.name
    if segue.identifier == "FirstToSecondView" {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
        secondViewController.name = namePass
    }
}
```

But at the moment that `prepareForSegue` is launched, self.name is nil

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: make it clear that you want that when you click ok the text in the alert view textfeild should pass the the other controllers variable ?? right

Comment: i have written my answer below , hope it will work fine , I'm also using the same method

Answer (score 0):

first you are to do is that set a tag for your alert as

```
alert.tag = 1
```

create a variable in your view controller as

```
class SBViewController : UIViewController{
//GlobalVariables
var demoText : String = String()

override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

the write a delegate method for your alert view and set you alert view delegate to self as

```
alert.delegate = self
var name : String = String()



  func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

            if alertView.tag == 20 {
                if alertView.buttonTitleAtIndex(buttonIndex) == "OK"{
                    var textFeild : UITextField = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)!
                    if textFeild.text != "" {
                    name =  textFeild.text


                  }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Why you write a alert.tag?
I have linked both views from the button using segue push. I only have stop the segue transition and show alert with textfield to capture the valor to send in prepareForSegue to secondView.

Comment: oka so simple write the code for segue separately and assign the textfeild text of alert to a global variable and then use the segue function

Comment: That is that I have implemented, but not works, because when I do "var namePass: String = self.name" in prepareForSegue, self.name is still nil